# HTML5 Canvas Image Operations

Tags: html, canvas

I have an application where I have to draw an Image on to a Canvas and this operation is done quite frequently ( about 60 times per second). However, there is a noticeable flicker when the image is rendered. Is there a better approach to drawing the image on the canvas other than from the Image Object ?

Is it better to copy image information from a Canvas to Canvas as opposed to from an Image to a canvas ? Suggestions to improve performance will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsperf.com/canvas-vs-image

On IE9 and Chrome 16 they are equal.

But FireFox 7 draws images 10 times faster than it draws canvases.

Comment: Thanks for the tests and mentioning jsperf.